# Console log not printing response after successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, console

I have weird situation, I have made a ajax call and it's working fine, the Status is 200 and I am getting my data from `php` function correctly. But it's not printing in `console.log` and not appending to my `<select name"a" id="section_id">..Response should append here..</select>` tag.

**script**

```
$("#student_class").change(function () {

    var class_id = this.value;
    var url = $("#student_class").attr("data-base_url");

  $.ajax({

      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: { class_id: class_id},
      dataType: 'JSON', 

      success: function(response) {
 // This console.log(response) not printing anything.
        console.log(response);
        if(response.success === true){
            $("#student_class_section_id").append(response.html_string);
        }
      }

    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
public function show_class_sections(){

    $class_id = $_POST['class_id'];

    $data = array("success" => false, "html_string" => "");

    $result = array();
    $result = $this->admin_forms->get_class_sections($class_id);

    if(!empty($result)){
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['html_string'] = $result;
    }


    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**Images of Ajax Response**

[image]

Why there it's printing the whole html page After success of request

Comment: In your console tab, there should be a `Default levels` combo box. Which log levels are checked? If `info` is not checked, that may explain why the logged text doesn't show in the console.

Comment: There are Default, Verbose, Info, Warnings, Errors. Last three are checked

Comment: Alright, then it's not the reason why the text is not logged.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
console.log(response);
```

With

```
console.log(response[0].value);
```

Comment: my problem is not only console.log() printing. There is html file code printing also after success message please view the picture